# Why do new engines have a case with a triangular tiling pattern?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, engine-design, engine-manufacturing

Take a look at the case of new engines such as the F-135:

[image: F-135 engine with case]

or the F-119:

[image: F-119 engine with case]

Why do they have a case with a triangular tiling pattern? Is this a new technology? A new material?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This type of structure is called [**isogrid structure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogrid). Solid walls are usually very heavy and therefore engineers use more weight-efficient structures such as [sandwich structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich-structured_composite) or stiffened structures with [stringers and frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-monocoque). A downside is the huge manufacturing cost compared to other options.

As you can see from [NASA Report CR-124075](https://femci.gsfc.nasa.gov/isogrid/NASA-CR-124075_Isogrid_Design.pdf) *"Isogrid Design Handbook"*, which was written 50 years ago, it is not a new type of structure.

Comment: Damn you, you remembered the isogrid, totally escaped my stress-demented mind  I think in the case of these jet engines, the manufacturing costs are not huge if we think about the viable options that fullfill the design goals: there might be none, actually.

Comment: I think we can go further back than NASA - how about the Vickers Wellington, for example?

Comment: @MikeBrockington That was a geodetic airframe, like the airship S.L.1. I don't consider them to be the equivalent structures because isogrid structures consist of a load-carrying skin with stiffeners forming triangles, while geodetic ones are a frame structure with many rectangles and mostly a non carrying skin like fabric.

Comment: The isogrid principle appears identical to the geodesic or geodetic construction of the R100 airship, Wellington bomber and Buckminster Fuller's domes. Is there any definitive difference?

Comment: @GuyInchbald They're optically very similar, but see my comment before. The skin of the three examples you mention is mostly fabric and cannot carry loads as the isogrid skin does. From a structural point of view one is a frame structure while the other is a stiffened shell.

Comment: "The skin of the three examples ... cannot carry loads" - Not correct. A skin of doped canvas, or of plywood, or whatever else, may have less strength than metal, but in both cases it is the COMBINATION of both that complements the particular characteristics of each.

Comment: @MikeBrockington "...cannot carry loads ... as the isogrid skin does". The skin will obviously transmit some aerodynamic loads to the primary structure, but it is not part of it.

Comment: @Gypaets Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 27):

This is simply a way to achieve required rigidity/strength and vibration dampening with less material than in a solid, even thickness  design.

Varying the weave pattern gives a relatively easy and a very efficient way to model and produce varying properties to different sections, without having to change the "base" structure thickness.

Successfully utilizing it does require advanced computing and manufacturing abilities, therefore it was not being used commonly in more ancient times.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it was at all uncommon in older times (depending on your definition of "more ancient".  Consider the common I-beam, for example, or structures build using tubing rather than solid rods, e.g. the tube and fabric structure of older airplanes.

Comment: You need to get fairly ancient: the [Schütte-Lanz SL-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sch%C3%BCtte-Lanz_airships#S.L.1_(Type_'a')) utilized it in 1909, and Vickers-Armstrong used [geodetic airframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_airframe) in the 1930s.  The calculations *are* complicated, though, which is why use of the technique only became common recently.

Comment: The structures you mention are somewhat different. The engine casings or shells in the pictures are are inseparable uniform solids, where as in the case of the airships and the V-A the skin and the grid were separate. Maybe glued or riveted together, dunno, but still separate "entities".

Comment: It might seem that the wimpy little ribs would not add much stiffness. What is invisible in the pictures is that the outside of each triangular facet is flat, but the inside is curved to form a continuous smooth circular cylinder. Therefore the middle of each facet is *very* thin, but the ribs surrounding the triangle prevent any impact damage from an internal failure in the engine from spreading across the whole casing. (In fact, I remember one "accident" where the company making a prototype casing actually cut right through some of the thinnest sections while attempting to machine it!)

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to regarding the required advanced computing capabilities, but note that the main reason for using equilateral triangles for the mesh (true "isogrid") is that it simplifies the design calculations a whole lot by making the properties of the whole lattice isotropic. A "waffle grid" (rectangular lattice) is much easier to manufacture but much harder to design. "advanced computing" actually enables more intricate and tailored lattice patterns than these two simple examples, so weird lattices have become a hot topic recently.

Comment: Regardless of the pattern, if someone is aiming to optimize weight, strength, vibration etc, it will require computing power, which was not available at competitive cost, say, 50 years ago. The sizzling hot generative design patterns that are filling the newsfeed of anyone interested in this subject are a whole different question. But yes, the simplier lattices do not require ludicrous investments form R&D departments nowadays, hence they are more and more common these days.

Comment: @Jpe61 Stress analysis has been "done" long ago using scaled models, manufactured from materials that are easier to work with. As long as the model is kept in the linear elastic region, and as long as there's no localized material anisotropy, then whatever you measure on the model applies (with proper scaling) to the full size structure. Some machined designs of this sort required dozens (sometimes >100) manually machined models as the optimization progressed. In some cases the models were machined wax, then investment cast, instrumented, loaded, measured, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Yes. Antoni Gaudí modelled the structure of  Sagrada Familia with strings and bags of sand almost 150 years ago. All kinds of modelling has been done for eons, modern computing has taken the optimization of structures to a whole new level.